# How to parse input data in transaction using go programming language?

Tags: transactions, golang

I know there are some resolutions about parsing transaction input data, but they don't work with go. I wander if there is any way i can use with abi available.

Specifically,  When i receive a transaction, i can parse the input data in transaction, to know which function it invokes and parameters it transfers.

Answer (score 0):

I found a already open source project realizing this. The source code is in https://github.com/Bokerchain/Boker

Comment: is there an example you can show of how you did it?